# Why is a jQuery set value of an input box posting as null to my controller in my MVC application?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

It's a bit of an odd one that I've never experienced before and searching hasn't returned any results that match what's going on.  I have a simple form in my MVC Web Application which uses the KendoUI library.  One of my input boxes is called 'CarName' which is set using jQuery.

Here is the dropdown list which has a change event, this copies the value to a standard input textbox.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("Cars")
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataValueField("CarId")
.MinLength(3)
.Events(e => e.Change("carChange"))
.Filter(FilterType.Contains)
.DataSource(source => {
    source.Custom()
    .ServerFiltering(true)
    .ServerPaging(true)
    .PageSize(80)
    .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
    .Transport(transport => {
        transport.Read("ReadCars", "Home");
    })
    .Schema(schema => {
        schema
        .Data("Data")
        .Total("Total")
        .Errors("Errors");
    });
})
.Virtual(v => v.ItemHeight(30)))
```

Here is the standard textbox

```
<input type="text" id="CarName" name="CarName" />
```

When the dropdown list is changed it writes a value to the input textbox.  Here is the `carChange` function that handles that.

```
function carChange() {
    var ddlText = ("#Cars").data("kendoDropDownList");
    var name = $('#CarName');
    name.val(ddlText.value());
```

The value is set, however, when I submit the form to my controller and set a breakpoint, the field `CarName` is `null`.  So, I can see the value changed in the form but the controller is given a null value as nothing get's posted.

If I manually type data into the `CarName` input, the data is passed to the controller without any problems.

I've never had this before so if anyone can shed some like that would be a massive help, it could be that my method of changing values is deprecated or something I'm not sure.

Comment: It would be great if you can share code to perform this process.

Comment: Is `CarName` a Kendo widget as well? If so, you have to trigger the `change`-event of the input field. Otherwise the visible content ist not written back to the model. If you enter the content yourself, the `change`-event gets triggered once you leave the element.

Comment: 'CarName' is a standard text input.  The function that this code belongs to is triggered by an `onChange` event from the dropdown list.  It's as if the value that's change isn't actually there at the time of posting but I can physically see it on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.  Despite the value being updated the KendoUI Popup seems to require the `change` to be triggered on the input itself.  Otherwise, it doesn't see the box as being completed.  In a normal form situation this `val()` method would work, but since we are using KendoUI it needs the `change` event in this situation.

Simply adding a trigger has solved the problem.

```
function carChange() {
    var ddlText = ("#Cars").data("kendoDropDownList");
    var name = $('#CarName');
    name.val(ddlText.value());
    name.change();
}
```